# QEMU: How to create a bootable-partitioned virtual disk?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, bios, qemu

I searched everywhere and no good result has been found.
I want to create a virtual disk using `dd` command and then make different partitions for it using `gparted` tool and finally install my OS on one partition (#1) and use `qemu` to boot up the whole virtual disk image.
here is what I try to do:

## Creating virtual disk image:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=./VirtualDisk.img bs=1M seek=1024
sudo losetup --partscan --show --find VirtualDisk.img -> bind VirtualDisk.img with /dev/loop2 device
```

## Creating partitions using the GParted tool:

```
sudo gparted /dev/loop2
#1. Create a new partition table -> msdos
#2. Create partition #1 -> Fat32, 512MiB -> /dev/loop2p1 (this one would be my bootable partition)
#3. Create partition #2 -> Fat32, 511MiB -> /dev/loop2p2
#4. Apply changes
#5. Manage Flags (partition one) -> boot, ESP
#6. Close GParted tool
```

## Burn the OS iso image on partition #1:

```
dd if=./myOS.iso of=/dev/loop2p1 bs=1M #the myOS is GRUB compatible
```

## Using the virtual disk image:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ./VirtualDisk.img -enable-kvm
```

## The result:

```
Booting from Hard Disk... -> Nothing else happens!!!
```

The funny thing is that if I use the following command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/loop2p1 -enable-kvm
```

myOS boots whithout any problems. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. My host OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Wow, an info I was looking for. Thanks I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by allocating sufficient RAM (-m option below):

```
qemu-system-i386 -vga std -m 1024 <raw_file>
```

(adjust your GRUB booting options as necessary before booting the image)